# I accidentally ended task ORACLE RDBMS in task manager

Tags: oracle

I accidentally ended task of oracle RDBMS in task managaer.

And now i cannot connect to oracle.

ERR MSG:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: Looks like you'd have to startup the database again.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Services, there will be one called OracleService{YOURDB]

Start that and you should be good to go.

There will also be one called Oracle[HOME]TNSListener.  That also needs to be running, but from the message above, it already is.  But should ever need to, you would start this before starting your database.